# "Destination Path Too Long" when moving an AndroidStudio project

Tags: windows, path

I have recently started to learn on Android application programming using Android Studio. I have my recent projects in `C:/`.

However, every time I want to copy or move these projects into another folder, Windows complains that the destination path is too long (the folders name are `color` and `drawable`).

So, how can I move these folder from `C:/` to somewhere else?

Comment: Maybe your file names are veeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeery long? near the limit of 255 characters?

Comment: I do not change anything. Everything is generated by the AndroidStudio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this problem by moving the project via AndroidStudio Refactoring.

1. Open the project that you want to move.
2. Change to *Project* view.
3. From there you can Refactor, Move your project to your desired directory.

AndroidStudio will take care of this path to long problem.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to move them to a path where the longest path length, with file name, is less than 255 characters.  There is no other solution.